# How to solve this Unexpected EOF error while parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am writing a code for a galaxy simulation using python and am required to extract certain values from the given data.

Here I ask the program for the number of particles in the different components.

```
print('ngas = %e, ndark = %e, nstar = %e\n'%(len(s.s.gas),len(s.s.dark),len(s.s.star)))
```

It works as expected...

Meanwhile, here I ask for the total mass for each component.

```
print('mgas = %e, mdark = %e, mstar = %e\n'%(np.sum(s.s.gas['mass']),np.sum(s.s.dark['mass']),np.sum(s.s.star['mass']))
```

This yields a syntax error (unexpected EOF while parsing). 
I have already checked that the masses are worked out individually, however when placed into the same print function, this error appears, confusing me massively.
In both cases, I am working with data of the same type, yet in the second case Python does not seem to comprehend it. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the second line and how am I to achieve what is required?

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is missing a closing parenthesis

```
print('mgas = %e, mdark = %e, mstar = %e\n'%(np.sum(s.s.gas['mass']),np.sum(s.s.dark['mass']),np.sum(s.s.star['mass'])))
```